# Running javascript whenever UpdatePanel refreshes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, updatepanel

I am using an asp.net update panel to refresh the content on a page when a menu item is selected.

Within the content that is updated are images which have a javascript reflection function which is triggered with the following line of code:

```
window.onload = function () { addReflections(); }
```

This runs fine when the page is first loaded but not when a menu item is selected and the update panel is run.

On previous projects using jquery code I have replaced document.ready with function pageLoad but there is no document.ready on this page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it's because that event isn't triggered by an update panel refresh.

There are ways to achieve this behaviour though, Ajax.Net has an EndRequestHandler function that you can hook into.

Here's a good example:

http://zeemalik.wordpress.com/2007/11/27/how-to-call-client-side-javascript-function-after-an-updatepanel-asychronous-ajax-request-is-over/

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
<script>

        // ASP.NET AJAX on update complete   
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(function(sender, args) {
           // your code here, eg initToolTips('/Common/images/global/popup3.gif');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

i think u should use

```
function pageLoad(sender, arg) {
    if (!arg.get_isPartialLoad()) {
        // in first load only
    }
      //every time the update panel refreshed
 }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this event:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx

`window.onload` is fired when the entire page is loaded. UpdatePanel uses an AJAX approach, so whenever it's updated and round trip ends, the page remains loaded and only a portion of this has been updated.

In other words, you need to do that "when a request to the server ends".